# MYSQL syntax for OR?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with 2 columns and a set of values called `MAIN`.
table1:

```
col1, int(11)
col2, int(11)
```

Set of values: 
MAIN: 1,3,4

`col1` and `col2` contain random integers between 1 and 10 for 1000 rows.  Then, any rows where `col1` and `col1` contain the SAME integer are removed.

I'm trying to pull those rows from table1 where:
`col1` contains values from `MAIN` and `col2` does not.
AND
`col2` contains values from `MAIN` and `col1` does not.

in invented pseudo code I have:

```
mysql_query("SELECT col1,col2 
             FROM table1 
             WHERE (col1 contains values from MAIN and col2 does not) 
             OR (col2 contains values from MAIN and col1 does not) ");
```

Any ideas on what the correct syntax is for this?

P.S. The set of values starts as a PHP `array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the [XOR logical operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor)?

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  ( col1 IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) XOR col2 IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) );
```

Small example of how XOR works:

```
SELECT true XOR true; -- false
SELECT true XOR false; -- true
SELECT false XOR true; -- true
SELECT false XOR false; -- false
```

That's pretty much your whole ( col1 in ( MAIN ) and col2 not in main ) OR ( col1 not in ( MAIN ) and col2 in ( main ) ), but written more succinct ;)

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was digging up. From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor): `a XOR b` is mathematically equal to `(a AND (NOT b)) OR ((NOT a) and b)`.

Comment: I've gone with this.  Thanks!  I will add, Thiefmaster's implode idea for the php array is also relevant.

Comment: @David19801 Oh, yes, definitely, just figured you knew this already, as it's not explicitly stated in your question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE (col1 IN (MAIN) AND col2 NOT IN (MAIN)) OR (col1 NOT IN (MAIN) AND col2 IN (MAIN))
```

MAIN should be your `list, of, values` of course.

If your PHP array contains only integers, you can use `implode(',', $array)` to get the proper value list to use in the `IN()` criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE (col1 IN MAIN and col2 NOT IN MAIN) OR (col2 IN MAIN AND col1 NOT IN MAIN)
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need smth liek this

```
SELECT 
  col1,col2 
FROM 
  table1 
WHERE 
 (col1 in (1,2,3) and col2 not in (1,2,3)) or
 (col1 not in (1,2,3) and col2 in (1,2,3))
```